# How to open and edit a txt file in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

First, I'm very new to python and this college class I took has been very unhelpful so sorry in advance.

I have a text document with book names. I need to make the user input an option. Each option coinsides with either displqaying the text document, editing the text document, or just stopping the program. I have the last
one. I can display it out of a loop. But, if I try to do it in a loop It jsut doesn't do anything, no error, just nothing.

```
f = open("Books.txt")
for line in f:
    print (line)

inp = ()
while inp != 3:
    print("1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit")
    inp = input("Please select an option.")
    inp = int(inp)
if inp == 1:
    print (f)
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question for better clarity?

Comment: Yea, give me a second sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `tell()` and `seek()` methods with file object (f)

Here is the code for it

```
f = open("Books.txt", "a+")
inp = 0

while inp != 3:
    print("1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit")
    inp = input("Please select an option.")
    inp = int(inp)
    if inp == 1:
        if f.tell() != 0:
            f.seek(0)
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                print (line.strip())
    elif inp == 2:
        book = input("What is your book name? ")
        f.writelines(["\n"+book])
   
f.close()
```

The output of this is as follows

```
1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit
Please select an option.1
HELLO
WORLD
TEST
1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit
Please select an option.2
What is your book name? Test2
1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit
Please select an option.1
HELLO
WORLD
TEST
Test2
1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit
Please select an option.3
```

Code explanation as follows

1. Open the file with append mode with readable access (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
2. The file cursor will be at EOF (End of File) in this case so you can easily append the new text to the file
3. When the input is `1` we first check the cursor location using [`tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.tell) which returns the integer value of the number of bytes read and if it's not in the starting. We move the cursor at starting of the file using [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek) (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
4. Since there are could be empty lines containing only new line characters which we can filter out while printing and later print the text by again stripping off the white characters using the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) method on the string because the print function automatically adds new line character
5. To write the line we need to pass a new character (line separator of course) and then the input name of the book

Comment: It won't let me. I'm too new. I'm sorry.

Comment: @AidenLumpkins No problem. I see you removed the accepted tag from my answer. Could you help me fix it? Where did it break?

Comment: It didn't break.  I just re did the tag. Hopefully it stays this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("Books.txt", "r+")
inp = 0

while inp != 3:
    print("1 - Display, 2 - Add, 3 - Exit")
    inp = input("Please select an option.")
    inp = int(inp)
    if inp == 1:
        for line in f:
            print (line)
    elif inp == 2:
        book = input("What is your book name? ")
        f.writelines(["\n"+book])
   
f.close()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama The file doesn't have write permission hence it will fail when user will input 2

Comment: @tbhaxor I saw that. I think I fixed it though. Thank you for the help.